# Segfault when pushing back to vector of vector in loop

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a code that pushes back data into a vector of vector, but I keep getting segmentation fault when I try to do this inside a loop.

I tried the following. I have two loops, one to count up to 5 and another that counts up to where the first loop is. I'm experimenting trying to create an variable size 2d vector in C++. My goal is that every subvector has a different size.

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    vector<vector<int>> v;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++i)
        {
            v[i].push_back(j);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try the pushback I get segmentation error. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance, Tiago

Comment: There are no elements in your vector v so v[i] doesn't exist and accessing it gives a segfault.

Comment: If you want to get picky, `v[i]` is undefined behavior, which you are seeing manifest as a segfault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`v` has no elements in it so trying to index it through `v[i]` gives you the segfault because its undefined behavior to index an element that doesn't exist.

Try adding a vector on each iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    v.push_back(std::vector<int>{});
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
    {
        v[i].push_back(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: Either that or declare the vector with five entries: `vector<vector<int>> v(5);`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still getting the segfault :/ Copy-pasted your for.

Comment: I need that both the parent and the nested vector to be initialized with push backs, without me specifying values.

Comment: We could also use the more cryptic `v.push_back({});`.

Comment: No, the increment in the inner `for` loop is incrementing `i` instead of `j`. Typo in the original code.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a `vector<int>` to `v` before you can add elements to the nested vector.

Also, you have a typo in the inner loop. You are using `++i` instead of `++j`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    v.push_back(std::vector<int>());
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
    {
        v[i].push_back(j);
    }
}
```

Another way to do this would be to resize `v` before the outer loop.

```
int size = 5;
v.resize(size);
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
    {
        v[i].push_back(j);
    }
}
```